# varying line thickness plot

Tags: r, plot

Is there an easy way of plotting a varying line thickness plot in R?

I have a dataset (with ~50k rows), where each datapoint has an associated size, and I'd like to plot that as lines. Assuming my data looks like this:

```
library(data.table)
data.table(x = 1:5, y = 1:5, thickness = c(1:4, NA))
#   x y thickness
#1: 1 1         1
#2: 2 2         2
#3: 3 3         3
#4: 4 4         4
#5: 5 5        NA
```

I'd like to achieve the following:

```
plot(1:2, 1:2, lwd = 1, type = 'l', xlim = c(1,5), ylim = c(1,5))
lines(2:3, 2:3, lwd = 2)
lines(3:4, 3:4, lwd = 3)
lines(4:5, 4:5, lwd = 4)
```

[image]

I understand that I can loop over all points and just do what I did above, but would rather avoid that kind of a solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A ggplot2 solution:

```
library(data.table)
dt <- data.table(x = 1:5, y = 1:5, thickness = c(1:4, NA))

library(ggplot2)
ggplot(dt, aes(x, y, size=thickness)) + geom_path()
```

[image]

Comment: great, that was easy :) seems like `ggplot` doesn't like that last `NA` (no biggie, adding any value there works just fine)

Comment: The `NA` is interpreted as the demarcation between different segments.  I think this is consistent with the behaviour in base plotting.